# PHP - Batch file not recognized as inerternal/external command or batch file

Tags: php, batch-file

I created a webpage that will run a PHP script to run a batch file.

```
  if($server == 'Chernarus') {
    system("cmd /c C:\serverCherno\instance_11_Chernarus_Overpoch\day\start_server_day.bat");
  }
```

However, it doesn't work, and I'm not sure why.

Upon AJAX Success, I have it print out to console the PHP response, and this is what it gets:

"'C:\serverCherno\instance_11_Chernarus_Overpoch\day' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Note: I don't have access to the server, so debugging this is going to be a pain...

Comment: You're certain that file exists, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only executing the batch file, remove the cmd from the command string

Try

```
    if($server == 'Chernarus') {
    system("start C:\serverCherno\instance_11_Chernarus_Overpoch\day\start_server_day.bat");
  }
```

Or

```
if($server == 'Chernarus') {
    system("C:\serverCherno\instance_11_Chernarus_Overpoch\day\start_server_day.bat");
  }
```